# C++ error: No instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++

I keep getting the same error with my code and still after searching through similar questions, I can't figure out what to do. Error occurs on the line stating "building[0].push_back(Person()".

```
std::vector<std::vector<Person()>> addPeople(std::vector<std::vector<Person()>> building)
    {
        std::poisson_distribution<int> distribution(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int test = distribution(generator);
            if (test >= 0 && test <= 6)
            {
                if (test = 0)
                {
                    building[0].push_back(Person());
                }
                else if (test = 6)
                {
                    building[0].push_back(Person());
                }
            }
        }

        return building;
    }
```

Comment: [OT]: `if (test = 0)` should be `if (test == 0)`. Increase your warning level to catch those errors.

Comment: For full context, could you please post the exact error as well in the body of the question? (Remember - your question should be worded so that others can find it, apply it to their similar situation, and find the answer thereof.) :)

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<std::vector<Person()>> building` should probably be `std::vector<std::vector<Person>> building`.

`Person()` in that context is a function taking nothing, and returning `Person`.